# Laravel API ResourceCollection - Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::mapInto()

Tags: laravel, collections

I have the following route defined in my web.php, to return a list of my Excepcion records in DB:

```
use App\Excepcion;
use App\Http\Resources\Excepcion as ExcepcionResource;
(...)
Route::get('/list/excepciones', function () {
    return ExcepcionResource::collection(Excepcion::where('active', '1'));
});
```

But I'm getting the following server error:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::mapInto()
```

If I change it to `Excepcion::all()` it works just fine. So, I'm not sure why I cannot use a where condition nor a scope. How can I filter the results here?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You forgot to call `get` to obtain the collection like so:

```
return ExcepcionResource::collection(Excepcion::where('active', '1')->get());
```

Answer (score 5):

For the record, if you call a relation in your resourceCollection (or anywhere else), don't forget that you must omit the parenthesis:

`MyResource::collection($this->relation);`

not

`MyResource::collection($this->relation());`

because the relation is not a method of the model, but a property.