# Laravel Call to undefined method HasMany::mapInto() when requesting data

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting a strange error which I cannot work out.

I have a `User` and also a `Partner` model. A user can have multiple partners. I am trying to retrieve a list of partners that the user has. I am also using Laravel Sanctum as my auth guard.

My relationship code is as follows;

In my user model

```
public function partners(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Partner::class);
}
```

In my Partner model

```
public function user(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

My route definition looks like so;

```
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum'])->group(function () {
    Route::apiResource('partners', Api\Partner\PartnerController::class)
    ->only(['index']);
});
```

and finally in my controller;

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    return PartnerResource::collection($request->user()->partners());
}
```

When I hit the endpoint though, I am getting the following error;

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Relations\\HasMany::mapInto()
```

I cant figure out the issue. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel API ResourceCollection - Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::mapInto()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52938592/laravel-api-resourcecollection-call-to-undefined-method-illuminate-database-el)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When You are Calling `user()->partners()` it returns `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany` Instance.

Resource needs to get `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` Instance.

You have to just call `user()->partners` ( Remove parenthesis )

Or call get method on `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany` Instance, to get Collection

```
user()->partners()->get()
```

Comment: Oh that makes a lot of sense ... Thank you for that